# Using timer for updating GUI: why it doesn't work?

Tags: android, user-interface, timer

I am creating an application for video recording and I overlayed the video preview with labels `txtStatus` and `txtTime`.

The camera button starts/stops the timer which periodically calls the `UpdateGUI` method. Running the debug I can see the timer is working - it calls `updateGUI` method every second but the method doesn't update the controls.

I would really appreciate if I could get any hint on how to fix this issue.

Here is the code:

This is the method which activates the timer:

```
private void startTimer()
{
    updateTimer = new Timer("TimerUpdate");
    updateTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask(){
        public void run(){
            settings.IncreaseRecordingTime();
            updateGUI();

        }
    }, 0, 1000);
}
```

This is the updateGUI method:

```
private void updateGUI()
{
    setStatusLabel();
    String strTime = settings.GetTimerString(); //strTime changes every second (it works as expected)
    txtTimer.setText(strTime);//the text doesn't change!
}
```

And this is the method which is called when the button is pressed:

```
private boolean onCaptureButton()
{
    settings.CaptureAction();
    videoPreview.setFrameCallback(settings);
    updateGUI();//here the function updateGUI() works as expected - it changes the txtStatus text from "Preview" to "Recording"
    setTimer();
    return false;
}
```

I added some comments as well (don't know why `updateGUI()` works when it is called at `onCaptureButton()` method and doesn't work when called inside the timer method).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After updating each control call `control.Refresh()` or `form.Refresh()` - this forces the controls to be redrawn immediately.

In your case:

```
txtTimer.setText(strTime); // the text doesn't change!
txtTimer.Refresh();
```

Comment: I tried to use txtTimer.refreshDrawableState(); but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

Timers run on a timer thread. You should only update the GUI from the UI thread. There are a couple of ways of doing this. One of the easiest is [AsyncTasks](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) or posting events to the the UI handler. Some functions work when called on nonGUI threads but that isn't well documented. I have never seen the refresh function. I have always used invalidate (UI thread) or postInvalidate (background thread). I thought that setText called that internally though.